# How to use mashape with python request library?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, text-processing, mashape

Unirest is not compatible with python3 and that's the library that mashape APIs' use on python projects.

I've decided to use python request library to make a POST request, but I'm getting a 400 HTTP error. Everything looks good to me, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
url = "https://japerk-text-processing.p.mashape.com/sentiment/"

myHeaders={
  "X-Mashape-Key": mashape_key,
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Accept": "application/json"
}

myParams={
  "language": "english",
  "text": tweet_text
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=myHeaders, params=myParams)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://unirest.io/python.html), UNIREST takes the argument:

> `params` - Request Body as an associative array or object

However, requests, per [its own documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), uses `params` to supply URL query parameters, not the request body.

Try using the `data` parameter to pass an actual request body instead; see [the docs again](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). You will probably have to keep double-checking parameter names in the two sets of documentation to ensure you're passing the right thing.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post

requests.post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)

**kwargs -- Optional arguments that request takes.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request

This function takes in header and params as inputs.


I'll try the data as the only input.

Comment: @avaldez1412 you will have to pass headers too, if that's where the API key goes.

Comment: Thanks, using data instead of params worked and I included headers.